# Generate values from db enum for jpa enum at runtime

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jpa, orm

I have seen on the internet ways to map a postgresql  enum to a java enum. But all the methods i have seen do not fare well when i modify the enum in the DB. What i would want to do is create the java enum values at runtime by querying the db or something along those line. How would it be best to proceed?
For example in the db i have the enum { 'a','b','c','d'} and i manage to change it in the db one day to {'a','x','d','e'}. Is there any good way to make sure i do not get consistency problems with enum in java.(Obviously manual update IS my last choice). I'm using a pre-9.1 pg db if it matters

Answer (score 2):

If you're updating enum definitions then you shouldn't be using enums. Use a lookup-table with a foreign key reference.

Enums are really for cases where you don't expect the enum to change, and where you're prepared to do significant work when they do change. In this case it would be entirely reasonable to expect to have to update all code that uses the enum if you change the enum's definition.